# document.execCommand in iframe don't work

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, execcommand

I'm working on my WYSIWYG editor. And I have code like this:

```
doc.execCommand(cmd, false, null);
```

The **cmd** argument would be 'Bold', 'Italic', etc. And the **doc** variable refer to the document in the iframe, which is initialized somewhere else:

```
doc = iframe1.contentWindow.document;
```

It works fine in Chrome, but in IE(my is IE9) doesn't work at all.

I debugged my code with the developer tool and found nothing wrong, the **execCommand** function just doesn't work.

I have searched through the Internet and couldn't found an available solution.

Would anyone give me a help?

Code sample:

```
function $see(e, o) {
    var that = this;
    ...
    this.e = $see.make('iframe', { 'class': 'editor' }); // editor iframe    
    this.e.onload = function () {  // call when the document is loaded
        var d = that.e.contentWindow || that.e.contentDocument;
        if (d.document) d = d.document;
        that.doc = d;
        that.doc.write('<html><head></head><body></body></html>');
        that.doc.body.innerHTML = that.ta.value; // that.ta refers to an textarea
        that.doc.body.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
        ...
    };
}
$see.prototype.exec = function (cmd) { 
    // call in an <a> tag's onclick event outside the iframe
    this.doc.execCommand(cmd, false, null); 
};
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because there are different methods to work with iframe in different browsers

here is how it should work

```
var doc= iframe1.contentWindow || iframe1.contentDocument;
if (doc.document)
 doc=doc.document;
```

**UPDATE**

ok i think i made a little mistake here is how it should look like:

```
var doc = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument.defaultView;
if (doc.document)
doc=doc.document;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it still doesn't work. It seems that contentDocument and contentWindow.document refer to the same object in IE and Chrome.

Comment: `this.iframe1.onload = function () {
  // that refers to this
  var doc = that.iframe1.contentWindow || that.iframe1.contentDocument;
  if (doc.document) doc = doc.document;
  that.doc = doc; 
  ...
};`
And another function to call execCommand:
`obj.prototype.exec = function (cmd) {
    this.doc.execCommand(cmd, false, null);
};`

Comment: please add this code in your question, because it is hard to read here. click on the edit button to edit your question

Comment: Sorry about that. I have put the code in my question. Please take a look.

Comment: I finally found that the problem was caused by missing 'href' attribute in <a> tag. But still thanks for your help.